# Как динамически изменить массив? React js

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, компоненты, react-hook

> У меня есть два компонента, в первом компоненте массив, который я хочу динамически изменить (например при нажатии на кнопку) и передать во второй компонент. Но я немного запутался. Буду благодарен за подсказку

> Первый компонент с массивом

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Context from './Context';
import Products from './Products';

function App() {
  let [arr, setArr] = React.useState([
    {id: 1, name: "Something1", price: 500,},
    {id: 2, name: "Something2", price: 1000,},
  ])


  return (
    <Context.Provider value={arr}>
      <div className="App">
        <Products />
      </div>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> Второй компонент

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Context from './Context';

function Products() {
    const arr = useContext(Context);
    return(
        <div className="Products">
            {arr.map(item => {
                return(
                    <div key={item.id}>
                        <h1>{item.id}</h1>
                        <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                        <h3>{item.price}</h3>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Products;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div onClick={clickHandler}></div>
  const clickHandler = () => {
    let newArr = [...arr]
    newArr[0] = {...newArr[0],id:25}
    setArr(newArr)
  }
```

подробное объяснение моего ответа https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7_7xvJ7Cjc

данные в Products сами обновятся после setState произойдет reRender компонента
главное не забывать про иммутабельность (работать всегда с копией объекта не мутировать объект (не изменять на прямую))

не принимай ответ как правильный мне самому интересно может есть более лаконичная запись моего ответа но решение верное